# How to merge two different topics and create a new one?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish odometry data from a STM32-F446re over serial and using rosserial_python for subscribing/publishing.

Since odometry messages are very big to transfer over serial, I only want to publish **pose** and **twist** without **covariance** matrices and would like to construct **odom** topic at the host side (add covariance at the host side).

How can I merge pose and twist messages to create a odom message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268666/how-to-merge-two-different-topics-and-create-a-new-one?/) by [pmundt](https://answers.ros.org/users/31451/pmundt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-08-12**:
If both of these messages are coming from the same source, it might be easier to define a custom message that contains a pose and a twist so that you can publish that on a single topic, and then write a node which converts that into a full odom message.

**Comment by [pmundt](https://answers.ros.org/users/31451/pmundt/) on 2017-08-12**:
Other than creating a custom message and writing a node, can I achieve this with using any tool (like any topic_tools feature)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To the best of my knowledge there is no such tool for automated merging of messages. As in your case a fair amount of additional information would need to be filled (i.e. covariances) your best bet is writing a small node yourself. You could also consider creating a custom message that contains all the data you need in compressed/minimal form (i.e. only transmit yaw angle and x,y etc.). I've taken a similar approach (albeit in the PC -> Arduino direction) for transmitting motion commands: [DiffDriveCommand](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_arduino_control_msgs/msg/DiffDriveCommand.msg) is the minimal pwm message sent over rosserial and the [translator node](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_arduino_control/src/joystick.cpp) takes care of translating ROS commands (joystick or Twist) to the minimal representation.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmundt](https://answers.ros.org/users/31451/pmundt/) on 2017-08-13**:
Thank you very much for giving me a starting point.